# 1-1 correspondence theorem

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

*Here is the correspondence theorem stated as follows:*

Let $A$ be an Ideal of ring $R$.There is 1-1 correspondence between Ideals of $B$ containing $A$ and ideals of $R/A$.
I have read the proof but didn't understand what it actually means and I can't understand things like show that if $B$ is an ideal of $R$ containing $A$ then $B/A$ is ideal containing $A$

Is there some simpler and intutive way of thinking how the    proof  of the   theorem proceeds ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\;B\;$ be an ideal of $\;R\;$ containing $\;A\;$, and now *define* :

$$B/A:= \{r+a\in R/A\;\;;\;\;r\in B\}$$

Prove that $\;B/A\;$ as defined above is an ideal of the factor ring $\;R/A\;$ . **Important:** don't forget that $\;A\le B\;$ !

Now, let $\;\overline B\le R/A\;$ (an ideal of $\;R/A\;$ ), and define

$$B:=\{r\in R\;\;:\;\;r+A\in\overline B\}$$

Prove that $\;B\;$ as defined above is an ideal of $\;R\;$ *containing* $\;A\;$ .

There you have the main part of the very important Correspondence Theorem for Rings, which allows us to write any ideal of the factor ring $\;R/A\;$ in the form $\;B/A\;$ , for some ideal $\;A\le B\le R\;$ .

You could also prove that both maps determined by the definitions above are inverse to each other, and that the correspondence respects the indexes:

$$[R:B]=\left[R/A:B/A\right]$$

Comment: I don't understand why you did $$B:=\{r\in R\;\;:\;\;r+A\in\overline B\}$$ 

Prove that $\;B\;$ as defined above is an ideal of $\;R\;$ *containing* $\;A\;$ . Isn't $B$ already defined as an ideal containing $A$.I know i'm missing something Please if you  can explain it to me I'll be grateful for it...

Comment: No @spectraa , it is not. $\;B\;$ is defined only as a subset of $\;R\;$ . **You** must prove it is an ideal and that it contains $\;A\;$ .

Comment: But the first line of your answer is "Let $B$ be an ideal of $R$ containing $A$."

Comment: @spectraa, that is for the *first direction* ! In the second one you have an idea of the factor ring and you're going to define your $\;B\;$ as shown there and prove that is an ideal containing $\;A\;$ ...This shouldn't be so hard to grab because, imo, you should have already studied the Correspondence Theroem for groups. Haven't you?

Comment: Yes @Timbuc I have . thanks  for explaining this to me...